# SSH URI with arguments

Tags: ssh, uri, openssh

I am just trying to match ssh parameters on a URI but seems like there is no option to do that, any idea ?

Shell command

```
ssh -A deploy-server.example.com
```

Similar URI
(How do I pass -A argument here )

```
/usr/bin/open "ssh://deploy-server.example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can't use ssh options on other programs.

But you can add the options to the ~/.ssh/config file

```
HOST myServer
 hostname deploy-server.example.com
 ForwardAgent yes
```

This works, as the most programs uses the standard ssh client.